# Equal vertical spacing for buttons in different divs

Tags: css, sass

Currently how it looks on page:

[image: Unequal buttons]

The goal: I'm trying to make the orange buttons set at an equal height regardless of the (blurred) text above it.

Relevant SCSS:

```
  .medium-2 {
    padding: .5rem;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    margin-left: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 450px;
    h4 {
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      color: #5d5d5d;
      font-family: $font-family-sans-serif;
    }
    p {
      padding-bottom: 10%;
    }
    .button {
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
```

Is there a non-hacky way to do this? Right now my only fix is to go into the html.erb file and add in some additional `padding-down` to the smaller block of `p` to push the orange button down in place.

Answer (score 1):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) can easily solve this for you.

```css
.content {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  margin-top: auto;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit rerum neque laboriosam perspiciatis sapiente optio ipsam ea magni, accusantium eos quaerat ullam facilis hic quo aperiam a iure porro inventore.</p>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```